# Count formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

```
| Description |     Account     |
|-------------|-----------------|
| Item1       | Account [AA]-BB |
| Item1       | Account [AA]    |
| Item1       | Account [AA]    |
| Item1       | Account [AA]    |
| Item1       | Account [AA]-CC |
```

I'm looking for a formula that would count the occurrence of Item1 in each of the accounts.
If the Item1 is showing in either Account [AA]-BB and Account [AA]-CC count should be subtracted. In the example above the count should be:

"Account [AA]" = 1  
"Account [AA]-CC" = 1 
"Account [AA]-BB" = 1

So to clarify. Account [AA] pulls the transactions from both Account [AA]-BB and Account [AA]-CC but is also a separate account.
If the Item1 shows in Account [AA]-BB and once in Account [AA] (meaning it's a duplicate) I want the count to show: 
"Account [AA]" = 0 
"Account [AA]-CC" = 0 
"Account [AA]-BB" = 1

Comment: Could you please provide more examples in order to clarify this? From my perspective, what you want to accomplish is not clear.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to accomplish. What is the difference between the two examples you gave, which result in different outcomes? Could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), clearly showing what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you can achieve that with SEARCH and IF functions.

`=if(SEARCH("AA",B2),1,0)`

It means it will count as 1, IFF string "AA" is a part of the value.

If you are looking just to count the "Item1" consider the COUNTIF function.

`=COUNTIF(A2:A6,"Item1")`

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Not exactly. So to clarify.  Account [AA] pulls the transactions from both Account [AA]-BB and Account [AA]-CC but is also a separate account. 

So if the Item1 is listed three times I want the count to be one.
If the Item1 shows in Account [AA]-BB and once in Account [AA] (meaning it's a duplicate) I want the count to show:
"Account [AA]" = 0  
"Account [AA]-CC" = 0
"Account [AA]-BB" = 1